# React Lazy loaded component loosing it's state (gets unmounted)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading, react-hooks

I have the below component that loads my components when required (upon route change).

```
function DynamicLoader(props) {
  const LazyComponent = React.lazy(() => import(`${props.component}`));
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <LazyComponent />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

And my Routes (using React-Router) looks like below:

```
            <Switch>
            {routes.map((prop, key) => {
              return (
                <Route
                  exact
                  path={prop.path}
                  render={() => (
                    <DynamicLoader component={prop.component} />
                  )}
                  key={key}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Switch>
```

This is working fine as far as mounting the component for each route goes, however it looks like with every change in the parent component, React is unmounting and remounting the lazy loaded component (instead of re-rendering). And this cause all the internal states to reset which is of course undesired. Can anyone recommend any solution please?
Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dynamic-comp-loading-sample-9zsc6) showing this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whenever the parent is rendered, the `DynamicLoader` recreates the `LazyComponent`. React sees a new component (not the same object), unmounts the previous one, and mounts to the new one.

To solve this issue use [`React.useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) inside `DynamicLoader` to memoize the current `LazyComponent`, and only recreates it if `props.component` actually changes:

```
const DynamicLoader = ({ component, parentUpdate }) => {
  const LazyComponent = useMemo(() => React.lazy(() => import(component)), [
    component
  ]);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <LazyComponent parentUpdate={parentUpdate} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dynamic-comp-loading-sample-r3of2) - to showcase the memoized `LazyComponent`, I'm passing the outer `update` to the `HomeA` component.

Since `useMemo()` caching is not guaranteed (react might free memory from time to time), you can write a simple lazy caching using a `Map`:

```
const componentsMap = new Map();

const useCachedLazy = (component) => {
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      componentsMap.delete(component);
    },
    [component]
  );

  if (!componentsMap.has(component)) {
    componentsMap.set(
      component,
      React.lazy(() => import(component))
    );
  }

  return componentsMap.get(component);
};

const DynamicLoader = ({ component, parentUpdate }) => {
  const LazyComponent = useCachedLazy(component);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <LazyComponent parentUpdate={parentUpdate} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-comp-loading-sample-bnvp3)

Comment: Thanks, looks good! Reading about useMemo, facebook seems to be suggesting that it's not guaranteed for useMemo to keep the values. What do you think about using Ref instead? or even a global variable to keep the already loaded components?

Comment: That's a good point. All you need is some kind of caching mechanism. I've added one using a Map, but you can also use lodash/memoize or any other caching mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This solved a really mysterious bug I had (component being unmounted, and its state reset, after I added lazy loading)

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue while rendering dynamic fields. And I've fixed it by using `@loadable/component`, it accepts cache parameter that avoids rerendering if the component is already imported.

Here's a basic example that I've been using;

```js
import React from "react";
import loadable from "@loadable/component";

interface Props {
  className?: string;
  field: "SelectBox" | "Aligner" | "Slider" | "Segment";
  fieldProps?: {
    [key: string]: any;
  };
  label: string;
  onChange: (value: string | number) => void;
  value: string | number | null | undefined;
}

const FieldComponent = loadable((props: Props) => import(`./${props.field}`), {
  cacheKey: (props: Props) => props.field,
});

export const DynamicField = ({
  className,
  field,
  fieldProps,
  label,
  onChange = () => null,
  value,
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label>{label}</label>
      <FieldComponent
        field={field}
        {...fieldProps}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you use `@loadable/babel-plugin`, dynamic properties are supported out of the box. Else you have to add `cacheKey` function: it takes props and returns a cache key.